# Any way to retrieve more changesets after an initial quick-clone?

Tags: git-tfs

I've cloned a TFS repository with the quick-clone command which gave me all the recent changesets. Is there a way to retrieve further, older changesets up to a certain revision in this existing repository? I don't really want to clone a new repository if I can help it.

Answer (score 1):

the `quick-clone` command checks out by default the last revision but perhaps you want to use the `-c` flag with the TFS changeset number...

For your information, each command have an integrated help with the flag `--help`, like:
`git tfs quick-clone --help`

Comment: I'd like a way which doesn't involve cloning a new repository if possible.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that in my opinion.
Perhaps in editing the config file in your .git folder adding a "tfs-remote" section like the one already existing for the "default" remote and after fetching that remote. But save your repository before doing that...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.

A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/28) was submitted which asks, *Is it possible to pull in earlier TFS changesets to the git repo before the quick-clone changeset?* One of the maintainers [responded](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/28#issuecomment-880421) that not only is the feature not implemented, but it is not feasible to implement it because of the way Git functions:

> Not, it's not. Or, at least, not easily. Because of git's sha1 thing, if you add a parent commit "P" to a commit "A", A will get a new sha1 id. So git-tfs can't backfill in front of a quick-clone commit.